# Emailing recurring invoices using quartz.net in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, rotativa

I am working on asp.net MVC application that needs to email recurring invoices to customers, i am trying to use quartz.net. I have to email invoice as attachment to every customer on certain date once in the month. I can send email with Quartz without attachments, but when i add attachment it doesn't send, when i click button that is linked with emailing method it does send email to every customers with the invoice attachment. Schedule emails are stored in database and invoices are generated in PDF using Rotativa. Here is my code:

```
public class Jobclass : IJob
{

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        InvoiceAddlinesController sche = new InvoiceAddlinesController();

        sche.Recurring(); 
    }
}

    public void Recurring()
    {
        int originalId = 0;
        string companyname = "";
        int suc = 0;
        string userloggedin = "";
        string loggedemail = "";
        string password = "";
        string Subject = "";
        string Message = "";
        string bar = "";
        string countDown = "";
        int seconds = 10;
        decimal? totalamount = 0;

        var scheduling = from e in db.Invoices
                         where e.schedule == "Schedule"
                         select e;     

            var sched = scheduling.ToList();
            foreach (var y in sched)
            {
                companyname = y.SchedCompanyname;
                originalId = y.SchedCustomerId;
                loggedemail = y.SchedLoggedemail;
                password = y.SchedPassword;
                userloggedin = y.SchedRt;
                totalamount = y.SchedTotal;
                Subject = y.SchedSubject;
                Message = y.SchedMassage;               

                bar = loggedemail.ToString();
                bar.Split(';');
                using (var message = new MailMessage("myemail@gmail.com", bar))
                {
                    var roata = from e in db.InvoiceAddlines
                                where e.AddlineID == originalId && e.userId == userloggedin
                                select e;

                    var roatainum = roata.ToList();
                    var model = roatainum;

                    message.Subject = "Message Subject test";
                    message.Body = "Message body test at " + DateTime.Now;

                    var pdf = new ViewAsPdf2("Gem", model, ViewBag.ind = originalId, TempData["user"] = userloggedin);


                    byte[] pdfByteArray = pdf.GetByte(ControllerContext);
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream(pdfByteArray);
                    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, "Invoice_Attachment.pdf", "application/pdf");
                    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
                    disposition.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    disposition.ModificationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                    message.Attachments.Add(data);

                    using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 587,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "@P#iop234")
                    })
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                    }
                }              

        }           

    }
```

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have no exception handling - are you sure that `Recurring()` executes without error?  I would think that either debugging the method, or adding some logging and exception handling would help greatly.

Comment: When i call Recurring() from view it execute without error, no exception.

Comment: And it sends the emails with attachments when called from a View?  However, I think you'll find that the context of the call from a View vs. from the Quartz scheduler will be different.  As it stands, we have no error message, and no other information about what could be going wrong (e.g an exception stack trace).  It's time to add exception handling, logging and debug the code.

Comment: I am new in ASP.NET, i have no idea how to do that. can you provide me with the  links to decent tutorial in logging and debug,